# How can I plot levels from a spreadsheet in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have a spreadsheet of intra-day support and resistance levels sorted by date. I want to write a script in Tradingview that plots these levels on a chart for backtesting purposes.

So far I tried listing them out and plotting each one but there is a 64 plot limit in Pinescript.
You also can't loop over a plot function as it returns the error "Cannot use 'plot' in local scope"

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the data as CSV into your script and make a float array out of it, like in the example below:

```
/@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true, max_boxes_count = 500)


float[] arF = array.from(
// paste your CSV data here, indent must not be a multiple of 4 for line continuation
      23000
      , 24500
      , 26000.12
      , 30100
      , 43200
      )

for i = 0 to arF.size()-1
    y = arF.get(i)
    l = line.new(bar_index, y, bar_index +1, y, extend = extend.both, color = color.red)
```